# Medion PC turning on but not booting up

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, post

A colleague of my mother has a problem with her pc and asked me to look at it. Now i've tried quite a few things but can't get it to boot up.. It is a medion pc and as soon as I push the power button all the fans and leds start running. I'm not hearing any beeps but that might also be because there's no speaker on the motherboard. Straight after pushing the powerbutton it shows "Power Safing Mode" on the screen and then it just goes black. I get no post or bios screen whatsoever. The graphics card fan is running like hell and the metal block gets hot enough to bake some eggs on there. I think the graphics card might be broken but I'm not sure. I've tried both the DVI and VGA port on the graphics cards and both of them on different screens to confirm that it's not just the port or screen.

A few thing I've also tried:

- Taking out the CMOS battery for about 10 minutes
- Make sure all the left over power was out of the capacitors (pressing the start button while it's not connected to a power supply)
- Boot up without the GPU connected to power (it's like internal power just 2 little cables instead of a 6/8 pin)

But nothing seems to work.. It doesn't have a video output on the mobo so I'm kinda stuck right now. Has someone got an idea how to troubleshoot further?

Ruben

Oh BTW: It's a basic Medion pc running W10 32 bit and the rest of the system seems to working correctly (can hear HD spinning etc)

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I do when I find a PC is not booting up such as your situation. The first being:

- Unplug everything I can. This means; Graphics Cards, Hard Drives, Disk Drives, USB's. Everything apart from the Power supply, CPU and Memory. Check if that works.

If that does not work then I would:

- If there is 2 or more sticks of memory take one out and leave the one closest to the CPU in and try it. If that does not work, try the other stick on its own in the same slot as the other one.

If that does not work:

- Try hardware out of a different system if you have any. Mainly the memory. You can swap CPU's but careful because you will have to re-apply thermal paste after taking off the heat-sink. If you don't have any, don't do it.

It could be down to a broken motherboard, in which case only a replacement can fix it. Maybe your mothers colleague has warranty with Medion, in which case the hardware can get replaced for free via an RMA.